# while uploading file on ftp site from vfp EXE running windows server 2008R2 , it creates only 0 KB file

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, visual-foxpro

Being a VFP database developer, requires some CAB/ZIP file (daily) to be created and uploaded on our ftp site. we are using windows server 2008 R2 for this auto exe.

Previously it was working fine, but due to some reason we had reinstalled server 2008, with all server's updates, now my auto-exe creates CAB file and also uploads file on ftp server, but it size on server is 0 kb

We are using following code to upload CAB file to ftp server

```
FUNCTION FTPPut

    PARAMETERS lcHost, lcUser, lcPassword, lcSource, lcTarget, lnXFerType

    *.................................................................................
    *.................................................................................

    DECLARE INTEGER InternetOpen IN wininet.DLL;
        STRING  sAgent,;
        INTEGER lAccessType,;
        STRING  sProxyName,;
        STRING  sProxyBypass,;
        STRING  lFlags

    DECLARE INTEGER InternetCloseHandle IN wininet.DLL INTEGER hInet

    DECLARE INTEGER InternetConnect IN wininet.DLL;
        INTEGER hInternetSession,;
        STRING  lcHost,;
        INTEGER nServerPort,;
        STRING  lcUser,;
        STRING  lcPassword,;
        INTEGER lService,;
        INTEGER lFlags,;
        INTEGER lContext

    DECLARE INTEGER FtpPutFile IN wininet.DLL;
        INTEGER hConnect,;
        STRING  lpszLocalFile,;
        STRING  lpszNewRemoteFile,;
        INTEGER dwFlags,;
        INTEGER dwContext

    PUBLIC hOpen, hftpSession

    lcHost     = ALLTRIM(lcHost)
    lcUser     = ALLTRIM(lcUser)
    lcPassword = ALLTRIM(lcPassword)
    lcSource   = ALLTRIM(lcSource)
    lcTarget   = ALLTRIM(lcTarget)

    IF connect2ftp (lcHost, lcUser, lcPassword)
        WAIT WINDOW 'Transferring....' NOWAIT
        IF FtpPutFile(hftpSession, lcSource,;
                lcTarget, lnXFerType, 0) = 1
            WAIT WINDOW lcSource + ' transferred.' TIMEOUT 2
        ENDIF

        = InternetCloseHandle (hftpSession)
        = InternetCloseHandle (hOpen)
    ENDIF
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I'm unable to answer your question without knowing what the program "connect2ftp" does, although I assume it connects and opens the FTP connection .

You might want to ensure that you include lnXferType = 2 so that you get binary transfer.

Since I don't have the code for the connect you're using, I'll offer the solution we always use for this, Robert Abraham's  FTP Class 2.07 available for download from http://leafe.com/download/ftpc_2.0.7_20090418.zip

It's very small and easy to use VFP solution, and an upload of a file goes like this:

```
LOCAL loFTP
SET PROCEDURE TO ftp.prg ADDITIVE 
loFTP=CREATEOBJECT('ftp_service') 

IF loFTP.OpenInternet("ABONNE", "PWD", "10.10.10.10", "21")
   IF loFTP.PutFTPFile("any.txt","local.txt", FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY)
      ?STRTRAN("File %File% uploaded","%File%","local.txt")
   ELSE
      ?loFTP.GetExtendedErrorCode(),loFTP.GetExtendedErrorMsg()
   ENDIF
   =loFTP.CloseInternet() 
ENDIF
RELEASE PROCEDURE ftp.prg
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, however still this does not work on Windows server 2008 R2, on my laptop (windows 10) it works fine. So something wrong with windows updates. before certain updates it was working properly now not working at all

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that you are using active connection (InterConnect lFlags parameter 0 - and also probably firewall is blocking in that case). Try using lFlags set to INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE:

## define INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE  0x8000000